# How can I convert xtend files to java?

Tags: xtext, xtend

I downloaded Osate source files from github. Project has some `xtend` files in it. can I convert them to `java` files.

Answer (score 2):

Xtend is transpiled to `.java` files by the Xtend Compiler in Maven, Eclipse, Gradle. => your projects build process should do that.